# Deactivating User with Connected Apps

Tags: user, user-management, deactivate

I am needing to deactivate a former system administrator.  The system administrator installed several managed packages and has Oauth Connected Apps.
Will deactivating this user have any effect on the managed packages or any other apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there will be no negative affects from deactivating the user. The Connected Apps and Installed Packages belong to the org, not to a user.